# When a question starts with "prove directly", how does one appropriately begin answering it?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Coming from a background without any experience I'm hoping to gain a little, with your help.
I am currently taking a semester of Discrete Math. This is a completely new way for me to look at mathematics and I am having a hard time with the mathematical syntax (to be frank I have problems syntax in all languages).
The question that I am trying to ask is the one in the title. *How would I begin to answer a problem that insists that I "prove directly".*
I realize that this question might be out of place, so forgive me, as this is my first post. If need be I can ask the actual question if that gives more context, but just needed edification on how to phrase my answer, and not an actual answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely, they are looking for an answer that verifies some definition from "first principles", rather than using some high-powered theorem to prove the result -- but it's hard to tell without more details.

Comment: Context would probably help.  My guess would be that they mean "as opposed to 'prove by contradiction'."

Comment: @ Gregory J. Puleo -That's exactly what they're looking for this is from Chapter 0 of the textbook. @lulu -Also was able to figure as much, but I don't know how to start, instinct would have me test numbers ad infinitum. Here is the prompt: Prove directly that $n^2 - 3n + 2$ is even $\forall$ $n \in$ $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: Testing all the natural numbers is not a good instinct.  To solve your problem, break it into cases.  Case 1:  $n$ is even.  Case 2:  $n$ is odd.